# Search product data not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried to make a search bar so users will be able to search products by searching on the product name but its not working and I'm not able to search a product.

This is my controller function:

```
<?php
class SearchController extends CI_Controller {
  function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->model('Search_model');
  }

  public function index(){
     $data = array();
  }

  function search_keyword(){
    $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['results'] = $this->Search_model->search($keyword);
    //laad de view
    $this->load->view('result_view',$data);
  }
}
?>
```

This is my model function:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search_model extends CI_Model  {  
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function search($keyword) {
        $this->db->select('product_naam');
        $this->db->like('product_naam',$keyword);
        $query  =   $this->db->get('products');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
?>
```

And this is my view file with searchbar:

```
<?php include_once('templates/header.php');  ?>
  <center>
    <h2>Zoek een cadeau</h2><br>
      <form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>SearchController/search_keyword" method="POST">
          <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="keyword" size="30px; ">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default " type="submit" value = "Search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
  </center>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <table>
    <?php foreach($results as $row){ ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->product_naam?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </table>
<?php include_once('templates/footer.php'); ?>
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem!,
thanks

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? Does the form not submit? Does it not return any values? Is there an error?

Comment: the problem is when i submit the search form with a product name in the field and I click on submit nothing happens and page gets refreshed, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think like() will help you much with your particular needs. Your best bet, I guess, would be to bypass the problem and use a where function containing your LIKE clause:

```
$this->db->select('product_naam')->from('products')
$this->db->where("product_naam LIKE '%$keyword%'")->get();
```

Or if you want pure ci you have to change your 'like' line :

```
$this->db->like('product_naam',$keyword);
```

For %$query you can use

```
$this->db->like('product_naam',$keyword,'before');
```

and for $query% you can use

```
$this->db->like('product_naam',$keyword,'after');
```

Comment: instead of 'title' needs to be product_naam for me right?

Comment: When I use you're first solution: $this->db->like('title',$query); i get this error when I load the page: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: query

Filename: models/Search_model.php

Line Number: 17

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/models/Search_model.php
Line: 17
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/SearchController.php
Line: 20
Function: search

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: @Learningprogrammingphp44: it was the example, you should change the table column and variable. Anyway, i have update the answer.

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159048/discussion-between-learningprogrammingphp44-and-anand-pandey).

Answer (score 1):

Because you use `$query->result_array();`, items should be taken by

```
<td><?php echo $row['product_naam']?></td>
```

> **result_array()**
>
> This method returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty
>   array when no result is produced

[CI documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-arrays)

Comment: yeh but doesn't work when I submit the form i want to search by keyword and than show the product name

Comment: * doesn't work* - Is page shown ? is array returned from a DB ? What's not happening?